# Gemalto OTP Tokens with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, one-time-password, two-factor-authentication, gemalto

Are there any NodeJS modules that will allow me to authenticate against the Gemalto IDProve 100 OTP tokens?  I have one of these from Amazon, and I thought the beauty of this device was that it didn't need to be attached to a server: you simply enter 2 successive codes into your own custom server, and an algorithm can continually authenticate against that device: http://www.gemalto.com/products/easy_otp_token/#

If there isn't a NodeJS module, are there any examples in .NET or other languages where you can read those two values and have an algorithm that can validate future codes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the IDProve 100 is an event based OATH token, that is based on RFC4226.

A design feature of the algorithm is that, that you ***cannot*** calculate future otp values based on two previous values. You need to know the secret key, that was implanted into the device in the factory. So Amazon or Gemalto would have to tell you the secret key, which hopefully both will not do.

The device itself does not need to be attached to any server, but the application (node.js) needs to communicate to some backend/server/module which is able to calculate the OTP value (based on the secret key and a counter) and compare it to the value the user entered.